# How I can get all Clients with MindBody API python

Tags: python, api, suds, mindbody

I am trying to get all [clients using MindBody API](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Documentation/ClientService), I tried this,

```
from suds.client import Client
from Helper.ClientService import ClientServiceMethods

# Making a call
calls = ClientServiceMethods()
result = calls.GetAllClients()
client_dict = Client.dict(result)
clients = client_dict['Clients']
client_list = clients.Client # transferring clients into a python list

#printing the lenght of received clients list
print len(client_list)
```

the above code will work but the issue is that it will not pull of more than ***27*** client, that's it. 
from [MindBody Docs](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Documentation/ClientService)  the **GettAllClients** should get up to 1000 client, the limit for a call is 1000 which means i can get up to 1000, but the problem is that I am note able to get at least that 1000, I am only getting 27 clients.

> Note: I am working with Demo Data, Sandbox which can anyone look them,
>   I used the Sample code from [their MindBody Python repository](https://github.com/mindbody/API-Examples/tree/master/Python)

I am working on  getting all clients data through the api,these clients can viewed  [from here](https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/adm/home.asp?studioid=-99)

Username:**Siteowner**  |  Password:**apitest1234**

Comment: Are you sure that there are more than 27 clients to fetch?

Comment: Yes I am sure you can check them for your self i will leave the password above, its can be viewed by anyone because they are just demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who's having problems with this too, this will be a big help for you.

> when we make call GetClients, mindbody will send clients but it will represent them in form of pages so that 25 client was the first page if u want to get the next 25 client you would have to call the page indexed  2 and so on and so forth.

in code this is how u would do this, using [API Example code](https://github.com/mindbody/API-Examples/tree/master/Python) `ClientService`, do this inside the method GetClientsByString

```
def GetClientsByString(self, searchStr):
        """Convenience method to find clients containing searchStr in their name or e-mail."""
        request = self.CreateBasicRequest("GetClientsRequest")

        # Since SearchText is just a string, we can assign it directly.
        request.SearchText = searchStr
        request.CurrentPageIndex = 1 # increase this number by one each time 

        return self.service.service.GetClients(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached it; very open to a better way that's not as API intensive:

```
    clientService = ClientServiceCalls()

    #get all client IDs

    clientResponse = clientService.GetClientsByString('')
    clientList = clientResponse.Clients.Client

    clientVisitsDict = []

    for c in clientList:

        #Call get ClientVisits API on each Client ID

        clientResponseVisits = clientService.GetClientVisits(str(c.ID))

        if clientResponseVisits.Visits:
            visitsList = clientResponseVisits.Visits.Visit
            for v in visitsList:

                ### your code here
```